# Does CommandLineParser support testability features?

Tags: c#, f#, command-line-interface

The package `commanddotnet` provides good [testability features](https://commanddotnet.bilal-fazlani.com/testtools/overview/). Does [CommandLineParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) support similar features? I could not find any info in the docs about this topic.

Comment: did you end up using commanddotnet?  if so, what was your experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [tests](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/tree/master/tests/CommandLine.Tests) should answer your question.